# How to apply max function in a SQL join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL queries ,could any one help me on this query, I have two tables below , need to join these tables location such that suppose I have both Etype on a same date the preference must be for Etype B over A, if there is not B then only fetch A

**Table1**

| Id | location |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | usa |
| 2 | uk |

**Table2**

| location | date | Etype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| usa | 2021-01-01 | A |
| usa | 2021-01-01 | B |
| uk | 2021-02-03 | B |

Result is expected like:

| Id | location | date | Etype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usa | 2021-01-01 | B |
| 2 | uk | 2021-02-03 | B |

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; what RDBMS are you *really* using. What have **you** tried to solve your provide? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple aggregation presuming you only two types `A` and `B` for Etype

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t2.location, t2.date, MAX(t2.Etype)
  FROM [table1] AS t1
  JOIN [table2] AS t2
    ON t2.location = t1.location
 GROUP BY t2.id, t2.location, t2.date
```

Comment: This works thank you

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to eliminate ties, or there are more than two `Etypes`, or they are not actually alphabetical in real life, or you have other columns you haven't mentioned that you can't or don't want to aggregate:

```
;WITH loc AS 
(
  SELECT location, date, Etype,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY location, date
         ORDER BY CASE Etype WHEN 'B' THEN 1
           WHEN 'A' THEN 2
           -- other conditions
           END)
  FROM dbo.table2
)
SELECT t1.Id, t1.location, loc.date, loc.Etype
FROM loc
INNER JOIN dbo.table1 AS t1
ON loc.location = t1.location
  AND loc.rn = 1;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f83d1f4362abb2e93d7cd34b4b02ac7)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT T.ID,T.LOCATION,X.DATE,MAX(ETYPE)MAX_ETYPE
FROM TABLE_1 AS T
JOIN TABLE_2 AS X ON T.LOCATION=X.LOCATION
GROUP BY T.ID,T.LOCATION,X.DATE
```

Could you please try the above ?